# How to disable touch outside screen dismiss view using MDCAlertController Material Design - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, material-components-ios

I am new iOS programming and now am fascinated in using `MaterialComponents` which provide by google. Now i facing one problem in component named `Dialog`.

When the view has been pop up on screen when i touch outside that pop up view and then that view has been dismiss. I don't want that to happen in my app.

I don't want user to click outside popup view to dismiss that popup view. What i want i just want user to click on action button that i provide for user's choice then the view should be dismiss when click on that action button only.

Really glade that you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MDCAlertController` is inherited from `UIViewController`.

So, in order to restrict user to click outside `MDCAlertController` you have to access its property named `view` and then `superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

I have completed one example using MDCAlertController

```
let alert = MDCAlertController(title: title, message: message)

    alert.buttonTitleColor = UIColor(red:0.03, green:0.62, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0)

    //MDCAlertControllerThemer.applyScheme(alertScheme, to: alert)
    let okayAction = MDCAlertAction(title: "Okay") { (action) in

        print("User click okay")

    }
    let cancelAction = MDCAlertAction(title: "Cancel", handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {

        // When the Dialog view has pop up on screen then just put this line of code when Dialog view has completed pop up.
        alert.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

use this.

```
let alert = MDCAlertController(title: title, message: message)

alert.mdc_dialogPresentationController.dismissOnBackgroundTap = false
```

https://material.io/develop/ios/components/dialogs/api-docs/Categories/UIViewController_28MaterialDialogs_29.html

https://material.io/develop/ios/components/dialogs/api-docs/Classes/MDCDialogPresentationController.html#/c:objc(cs)MDCDialogPresentationController(py)dismissOnBackgroundTap